# Uploading file with jshelper in CakePHP 2.2.1

Tags: ajax, cakephp, file-upload

I am trying to made upload files with jshelper.

In my view:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Form', array(
    'inputDefaults' => array(
    'format' => array('before', 'error', 'label', 'between', 'input', 'after'),),
    'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'
)); 
echo $this->Form->input('Form.file', array('type' => 'file', 'id'=>'file'));
$this->Js->get('#file')->event(
    'update',
    $this->Js->request(
        array('controller' => 'ControllerForm','action' => 'actionForm'),
        array(
        'async' => true, 
        'method' => 'post', 
        'dataExpression'=>true,
        'data'=> $this->Js->serializeForm(array(
            'isForm' => false,
            'inline' => true,
            ))
        )
));
echo $this->Js->writeBuffer();
echo $this->Form->end(); 
?>
```

In my controller:

```
public function actionForm(){
    debugger::dump($this->data);
}
```

But `debugger::dump` output empty array.

Comment: Debugging thoughts: Are you getting any JS errors in your browser console? What does CakePHP's generated JS look like? Is the request actually being sent? What does the request body contain?

Comment: Not an answer to your question directly, but the CakePHP uploads plugin may be an easier way to achieve the same functionality

Answer (score 0):

Man as I know you cannot send file using ajax (include xhrRequestObject2 in Chrome). Firstly in server side you check post data instanted debug($_FILES), but that as I wrote is empty. Use old good iframe to send data to server.